# Excel: Select entire row but starting from a certain column

Tags: microsoft-excel

If this how to select the entire row...

```
COUNTIF(1:1, ">0")
```

How to start from a certain column like this: G1 ~ infinity?

```
COUNTIF(G1:1, ">0") // this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:
The COLUMNS function can help us get the total number of columns `-` the number of columns before the G1 column `=` the number of columns we want.

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(G1,0,0,,COLUMNS(1:1)-COLUMN(G1)+1),">0")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At first there is no infinity in Excel. There is [row and column limit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). So you can define this range specifically.

Column limit is now `16 384` (does not apply for `*.xls` and could be changed in future versions)

So you range could be: `G1:INDEX(1:1,1,16384)`

But this force the Excel to test even empty cells in the range = BIG performance loss.

It depends on what data you are processing, but not defined column count is usually sign of bad table design.

Answer (score 0):

*The most easiest is:*

`=COUNTIF(1:1, ">0")-COUNTIF(A1:F1,">0")`

- Cell references are adjustable.